# Angular 2 - detect when a bonded property receives a value

Tags: angular, property-binding, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I would like how to know when a bonded property receives a value, even if it's the same value.

For example

That is a feature component

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    OnChanges,
    SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'feature-component',
    templateUrl: './template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./style.sass'] 
}) 
export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit, Onchanges {

    @Input() bondedProperty: any;

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges) {
        // not called inside the setInterval function
        console.log('the bonded property received any value.');
    }

}
```

The component of the app

```
import {
    Component,
    AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./style.sass'] 
}) 
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    bondedProperty: any;

    constructor() {
        this.bondedProperty = 10;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const
            interval = setInterval(
                () => {
                    this.bondedProperty = 10;
                    console.log('function called after interval');
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }, 5000
            );
    }

}
```

And finally, the template of the app

```
<feature-component
    [bondedProperty]="bondedProperty"
>
</feature-component>
```

The problem is that if the same value is assigned in `bondedProperty` `ngOnChanges` isn't called, and the `ngDoCheck` method doesn't solve my problem because I would not know if the "change" was in `bondedProperty`.

Comment: You can use a setter and a getter on the bondedpropery

Comment: Using @ViewChild you can call child component method so that might help you

Comment: There might me something similar to componentShouldUpdate like in Angular as in react.. where we got current state and new State of component

Comment: Looks like some else is wrong in your project, created this [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-54059234) and you can see that your code is working.

Comment: @benshabatnoam in your example you set the `bondedProperty` to a different value in `ngAfterViewInit` than in the constructor. It works with different values but not if the value is the same as the previously set value.

Comment: @changulpaye how? Post a example about what do you want to say, please.

Comment: @Hypenate setters work only if the attributed value is different.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this can't be achieved with `ngOnChanges` or `@Input setters` as Angular is designed to only call `ngOnChanges` or the `setter` if the value actually changes.

If you want to detect new values even if they are the same as a previous value what you really want is probably to detect some kind of event. You could use an RxJS `BehaviorSubject` for that kind of purpose.

**FeatureComponent**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject }  from 'rxjs';
@Component({
    selector: 'feature-component',
    template: 'property: {{ bondedProperty$ | async }}',
    styleUrls: ['./style.sass'] 
}) 
export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit, Onchanges {

    @Input() bondedProperty$: BehaviorSubject<any>;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.bondedProperty$.subscribe(value => 
        console.log('the bonded property received any value.')
      );
    }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject }  from 'rxjs';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: '<feature-component [bondedProperty$]="bondedProperty$"></feature-component>',
    styleUrls: ['./style.sass'] 
}) 
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    bondedProperty$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);

    constructor() {
        this.bondedProperty$.next(10);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const
            interval = setInterval(
                () => {
                    this.bondedProperty$.next(10);
                    console.log('function called after interval');
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }, 5000
            );
    }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-54059234-eshtnr

Comment: Thanks. I know this solution, but I didn't want use it cause' my question is to be used in a external library, and this solution will require more complexity for the user. 
But if there is no other solution, will have to be that.

Comment: @rplaurindo Well I guess you have to ask yourself why your feature component should care about an input property being set to the current value it already has. Your component doesn't need to be rendered again so Angular doesn't care about it. If you would state your actual use case people might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way it to change your `bondedProperty` variable to be an object.

before:

```
this.bondedProperty = 10;
```

after:

```
this.bondedProperty = { 'value': 10 };
```

This way the change detection will catch your update event if the value in it is the same.

[StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-54059234)

Comment: Yeap, cause' you pass a differente value, a literal object, despite having the same attributes it's a new object, with another address in the memory.

Comment: Correct, is this suits you?

Comment: No, but would can help to someone understand why it works.